# Owl-Carousel: I need to apply rtl: true property only when page load in arabic. Not all the time

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

In my case, if have site with both languages, english and arabic. When I turn this(rtl:true) property on it reflects in english site as well.
It should be apply when  tag have the dir="rtl".

For reference of owl-carosusel
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/rtl.html

Please guide, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand this issue below code may help you.

```
var mydir = $("html").attr("dir");

if (mydir == 'rtl') {
     var rtlVal=true
}
else{
     var rtlVal=false
    }
    
$('Your ID').owlCarousel({
      rtl: rtlVal,
      loop: true,
      items: 1,
      nav: true,
      dots: false,
      navText: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line of code in your css, if HTML language is arabic then your carousel converts to be right sided.

```
.owl-carousel:lang(ar) { direction: ltr !important; }
```